# Feasibility of Google Data Studio for Multi-tenancy SaaS application

Tags: looker-studio

We are working on a SaaS product and considering Google Data Studio as platform to build the analytics instead of create visualization within our product backend for easier flexibility and also allow use to bring in data from 3rd party sources.

Should we be create some custom connector for our application where customer would provide authentication key and using that our connector will fetch customer specific data and store in Google Data Studio?

Can we use reports gallery to publish our product analytics? I am not sure how would we handle upgrades where if we add more data sources. It should come easily for end users.

Looking forward to expert advise.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Can we use reports gallery to publish our product analytics?" 
Are you looking for something different than being able to share the report as explained in https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7459147

Comment: Yes, I am visualizing each tenat as separate company and they will own their reports. Our product will push data to Google data studio for each tenat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Data Studio. You likely will need to look into [creating a community connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) & look through some of the help-center documentation [about sharing](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6287179?hl=en). If your data is stored in one of the first-party connectors (such as BigQuery or Sheets), you won't need to develop a new community connector.

The reports gallery wouldn't be necessary to publish the product analytics, but it would be an option. I would suggest managing a separate report for each customer along with a separate data source that is created off the community connector you would develop to bring your data in.

Comment: Thanks! I also had similar feeling to creating a custom community connector. Data would be stored in GCP hosted SQL database. Where can I find list of first party connectors?

Comment: https://datastudio.google.com/c/datasources/ The top section labeled "Google Connectors"

Comment: @diminishedprime, will it be a good idea to create different datasources and different report for each client ? As report is same just the data should be client specific. 
Do I need to build a custom API connector which returns data for that client only.